# Excel function to Vlookup containing text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I’m using an index match to test 3 criteria and return a result (like an xlookup), however I’m running into some trouble with my third criteria. My first two are simple and work perfectly, just that the cell in the row in question is found in a table as an exact match, but the third criteria needs to be that the column contains text in question. For example, let’s say I have a row for sales people, and his title is “district manager”. I want to be able to look up my sales persons, region, salary, and that his title contains the word “manager” in an XLOOKUP fashion.

I tried XLOOKUPS and INDEX MATCHs because my lookup has multiple criteria, but where one of my criteria is that the text in the cell has to be somewhere in this column in the data table, I can’t find it. If I could use an if(is number(search) could tell me the row number(s) it found it in, or I could use if(isnumber(search)) as a criteria, then it would work. My criteria 3 is currently that (cell contains text)=(column of text cells), but since I don’t need an EXACT match, just that the column’s text CONTAINS it, it doesn’t work.

Comment: use `=@FILTER(A:A,(B:B=123)*(C:C="Abc")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Manager",D:D)))`

Comment: ... or `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,(B:B=123)*(C:C="Abc")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Manager",D:D))),0))`.

Comment: Would it be possible to do this with an XLOOKUP function? Just to save on spreadsheet performance in the long run

Comment: @Sam If there are no duplicates, then you can use `XLOOKUP()` as well, same way like Scott Sir & VBasic Sir has said. `=XLOOKUP(1,(B:B=123)*(C:C="Abc")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Manager",D:D))),A:A,"")`